How do I align an icon in the top left of a Column that has verticalArrangement of Center
As title says, I have a compose Column where I center the contents vertically but I want an icon in top left.

If nothing else, you could wrap the Column() in a Box() and position the icon within the Box(). Or, consider switching to ConstraintLayout(), using a suitable chain for your centered column contents while also setting up suitable anchors for your icon.

If you want the Column content be centered in the screen without having any offset from the Icon on the top, then use a Box as suggested in the comments:
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        // ...
    }
    Icon(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)
    )
}

Note that with this approach, the Icon could overlap the Column items when the Column is filling the full screen height.
